# Standard and easy mySQL query goes wrong

Tags: php, mysql

**Problem solved, it was an session crash causing connection to live database rather than local. Thanks anyway for those who tried to help me...!**

For some reason I can't figure out why this query don't work. Does anyone see the problem or can give me any guesses what's wrong?...

**Many have wondered wheres my variable is set, All "MYTABLE, MYCOLLUMN, MYVARIABLE" is placeholders. As u can see the query works in phpmyadmin so nothing wrong with those.**

> - Query works directly in Phpmyadmin
> - I get no error from mysql_error
> - I get no error from my PHP error checks more than that variable not set
> - There is no "same name variable in earlier query" crash

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors","1");
ini_set("display_startup_errors","1");


        $result_ag = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `MYTABLE` WHERE MYCOLLUMN='$MYVARIABLE'");

    /*  while ($data_ag = mysql_fetch_array($result_ag)){
          $lKundNrslut[] = $data_ag['lKundNr'];
        }
        var_dump($lKundNrslut);
    */

        $qwert = mysql_fetch_array($result_ag);
        echo $qwert['lKundNr'].'DFQ';
```

I really can't find the problem that's probably just and easy miss in front of my eyes and would appreciate any ideas how to solve out this thing...

Comment: And where is your `$MYVARIABLE` defined? It is not in this code

Comment: What data `$MYVARIABLE` holds?

Comment: Is correct `MYCOLLUMN`? maybe a typo?

Comment: Can you use var_dump to output whats in the array $qwert - is it empty?

Comment: Those are placeholders, as said in the header query works in phpmyadmin and are therefor no spelling wrong with those..

Lissy: Yes, it gets returned as no data (NULL).

Comment: To be even more clear: your mysql table is called `MYTABLE` and your column is called `MYCOLLUMN` (including double `L`), right?

Comment: No, They're NOT. THOSE are placeholders. They ARE NOT THE PROBLEM, because the query gives my result in PHPmyadmin. Thx anyway for trying to help..

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `MYTABLE` WHERE MYCOLLUMN='$MYVARIABLE'";

echo $query;

$result_ag = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());// remove this bit in production
```

and now see about the deprecation of PHP's mysql_ API

Comment: As I said in the header, i don't get any mysql errors, but the query still works in phpmyadmin. Still query does'nt return any data from my php document.

Comment: Yes, I have already done that and after that copy+paste it into phpmyadmin where it workes... I just thought that an commentout echo line of query in question would not help.

Comment: Well, it helps us. (Or at least it might, if we could see it) :-)

Comment: I've doubt that but very well, heres the echo.
SELECT * FROM `MYTABLE` WHERE MYCOLLUMN='201401'